# ADHoc Distribution Provisioning profile with one UDID is working in two devices

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution, udid

I have to do one POC in ADHoc Distribution provisioning profile to find whether my profile get invalid after adding new devices. But finally stuck with a strange issue.

I have created one provisioning profile which is having  2 UDIDs and successfully run that iPA in these two devices.
After that i removed one UDID from the provisioning profile and created another iPA.That iPA is also running in both devices. Looking Strange!!

I checked that iPA's provisioning profile, but it only contains 1 UDID. Still working in two devices HOW?

Please share some ideas!!!

Comment: After removing 1 UDID, you have to again download latest provisioning profile and make build with that only, then you check, ipa will work only with 1 UDID with related device.

Comment: I created iPA with new provisioning profile only.

Comment: Delete the old build, and install new one.

Comment: That won't delete the old provisioning profile from the device, so even after doing that,  the app will stilll run. The provisioning profile would need to be removed from the devices. See my answer below for more details as to why.

Answer (score 1):

You deleted the old provisioning profile from your Mac, but you also would need to delete the old provisioning profile from the device that you deleted the UDID for.  The old provisioning profile with the 2 UDIDs will remain on the devise until it expires. When you try to run the app on the device, iOS will install the embedded provisioning profile on the device, and then it will look for any valid provisioning profile that will allow the app to run on that device, **even if it is not the one that was embedded with the binary**.

To clean up the old provisioning profile from the device, plug the device into your Mac, and go to the Devices window in Xcode. Right click on the device on the left and select Profiles. Delete the old one(or all of them if you want to ensure it is complete.

If you want to revoke access to an app running on old provisioned devices, you would need to revoke the certificate used to sign the old build with the 2 provisioning profiles. Then create a new certificate with a new provisioning profile with the single UDID. The reason is that iOS only cares if there is any provisioning profile that would work on a device. Once you put that provisioning profile out there with the UDID, you can't invalidate just that provisioning profile ad hoc. You can however, invalidate the cert.

Comment: I have checked the way you said. I went to Device section in Xcode and try to find the provisioning profile installed through xcode. But in it "NO PROVISIONING PROFILES INSTALLED......" is the message i am getting. Since i am working with client project i am not permitted to revoke the certificate everytime

Comment: If there are no provisioning profiles on the device, and the embedded profile does not contain the device UDID, the application will not be permitted to run on the device. The only thing I can think is that the provisioning profile(s) aren't showing in the devices window.  Could you do a factory reset on the device that is no longer in the profile and try running again?

Comment: Also, it could be this Xcode bug where provisioning profiles are not showing in the Xcode devices window: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/45086

Answer (score 0):

have you deleted old profile?
it's possible that you've double profile installed on your mac?
you can use iPhone Configuration Utility app to find out.

Comment: i have deleted the old provisioning profile and i checked the profile inside the iPA , that is having only 1 UDID. Still it is installing in two devices.

Comment: obviously have you deleted UDID from your apple developer?

Comment: not only from the apple portal. after deleting the udid i have downloaded the provisioning profile and installed that then i created the ipa.  still it is working in 2 devices.

Comment: There's no need to delete the UDID from the Apple developer site list of devices.  You need to delete the 2 Device provisioning profile from the second device. See my answer below for clarification on how iOS devices work with profiles.